# Nginx Site Redirect / Fallback

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have noticed a strange behaviour on one of my servers and I am not able to understand how is it working, and most important if such configuration is making a redirect as I am not sure how I end up in https.

I have two subdomains:

```
test.domain.com
```

and

```
test2.domain.com
```

In the config of test
I see a wrong value for the server_name as:

```
test server config

server {

        root /var/www/html/test/public;
        index index.html index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name test test.domain.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; # =404;
        }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = test.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name testings test.domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Now test2 has same server_name logic

```
server_name: test2 test2.domain.com

**and no ssl enabled**

server {

        root /var/www/html/test2/public;
        index index.html index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name test2 test2.domain.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; # =404;
        }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

#    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
#    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
#    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
#    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
#    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
#    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
#    if ($host = test2.domain.com) {
#        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
#    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name test2 test2.domain.com;
#    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

There is a warning saying that test2 is already in use but still does work.

Now the strange thing is that when I go to https://test2.domain.com it does work,

but brings me the root of test and not test2;

while what makes sense is that I am redirected to the root of test2 if I open http://test.domain.com

I expanded the certificate of test2

```
certbot certonly --nginx -d "test.domain.com,test2.domain.com"
```

so the same certificate should work for both.

My question is how am I pointing to the root of test
when I am opening https://test2.domain.com?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing strange - you get is what you configured. There is nothing weird or magical. It's just what tcp sockets are listening with your config. It's obvious even without reading nginx docs.

You didn't say is it two servers configured on one host or on two different hosts and to what IPs your `test.domain.com` `test2.domain.com` are resolved - it's very important for your question and not obvious at all.

**First guess - you talk about two nginx servers with different IPs and you just mixed up the IP addresses of the servers in DNS configuration**

> https://test2.domain.com ... brings me the
> root of test and not test2

`test2.domain.com` resolves to IP of the server with `root /var/www/html/test/public`

> I am redirected to the root of test2 if I open http://test.domain.com

`test.domain.com` resolves to IP of the server with `root /var/www/html/test2/public`

**Second guess - you talk about one nginx server with two sites configuration and `test.domain.com`, `test2.domain.com` are resolved to the same host's IP**.

There are

- one ngninx's “Server Blocks” listening IP:443 and IP:80 (`server_name test.domain.com`)
- and another ngninx's “Server Blocks” listening IP:80 (server_name `test2.domain.com`).

> https://test2.domain.com ... brings me the
> root of test and not test2

When you open **https**://**test2**.domain.com it resolved on you client as **IP:443** since you want **HTTPS**. Nginx shows you **test's** content because on port 443 only `test.domain.com` with `root /var/www/html/test/public` is configured.

> I am redirected to the root of test2 if I open http://test.domain.com

When you open **http**://**test**.domain.com it resolved on you client as **IP:80** since you want **HTTP**. Nginx have 2 `server_name`s for 80 port: `test.domain.com` and `test2.domain.com` and should select `test.domain.com` and return content from `/var/www/html/test/public` but you state it returns `test2.domain.com`'s content.
It's possible if `test.domain.com` points to IP of server with `root /var/www/html/test2/public` - see first guess.

Also
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html